# How to make the button in such a way that hovering it results in the rotation and spinning of another object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, hover

I have the following code in which the star is automatically "spinning" around the crescent and hovering it makes it "rotate". There is also a button on the left side: when it is hovered, it only changes its background-color and text-color; however, **I want the star to start *spinning and rotating* when the *button* is hovered** (and also want the effects of the button i.e. changing its background color and text color, to maintain simultaneously). I tried using different codes but everything I do results in messing the code up further.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        position: relative;
        right: -500px;
        bottom: -150px;
      }
      .moon,
      .star {
        background-position: center; /* Center the image */
        background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
        background-size: 120%; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */
        -moz-border-radius: 50%; /* to make circle shape */
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        border-radius: 50%;
      }
      .moon {
        background-color: transparent;
        background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bcIk.png");
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 50px;
      }
      .star {
        position: relative;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjbgR.png");
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
      }

      .rotate {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-animation: circle 10s infinite linear;
      }
      .moon:hover .counterrotate {
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        -webkit-animation: ccircle 10s infinite linear;
      }

      @-webkit-keyframes circle {
        from {
          -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
        }
        to {
          -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
        }
      }

      @-webkit-keyframes ccircle {
        from {
          -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
        }
        to {
          -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
        }
      }

      .moon:hover .counterrotate {
        animation-name: inherit;
        animation-duration: 5s;
        transition-duration: 0.2s;
      }

      button {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 16px 32px;
        font-size: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 2px solid green;
        display: inline-block;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
        position: relative;
        left: -350px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        bottom: -100px;
      }

      button:hover {
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid white;
        transition: 0.5s;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: green">
    <div class="moon">
      <div class="rotate">
        <div class="counterrotate">
          <div class="star"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button>Hover</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: With just CSS you cannot ' select ' and ' manipulate ' elements(1) depending on actions on other elements(2) which have no relationship ( descendant, sibling down the DOM tree  ) with the elements (1) that you want to manipulate. You can do it with javascript.

Comment: @MihaiT: Doing that with JS is also fine. Could you post an answer showing how to do that? (I'll edit it to include JavaScript tag)

Comment: First, you need to try it on your own. Share what you have tried (  using js ) and we can help you from there

Comment: @MihaiT: Sorry. I'm a beginner and have just started HTML/CSS, I don't know about JS.

Comment: Well unfortunately StackOverflow is not a free code making community . THere are other communities out there that can help you ( for a price ) . Here we can help you debug/improve your code but not make the code for you. Maybe you are lucky and someone will write the code for you but i doubt it.

Comment: Are you able to move the button above the .earth div? You could then use sibling selectors.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what hovering on the moon is to do? The problem is, if the user hovers and the result of that is to rotate the moon counterclockwise then it stops being hovered almost immediately and so starts to rotate the other way, then gets hovered again and so on. What effect is actually required and does it have to be on hover rather than say click?

Comment: @AHaworth: Thanks for giving attention to my question! Yes, I'll try to edit it to elaborate.

Comment: Does 'rotating' mean the star turns around its center and 'spinning' means the star goes 'around' (moreorless) the moon? Is there now no concept of 'counterrotating'?

Comment: @AHaworth: You're right on both counts. I removed counterrotating because it was kind of confusing but it's still there in the code (because the entire code isn't mine). Also, I'm new to the field, so I'm confused by counterrotating, rotating and spinning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood the requirement correctly, you do not need Javascript for this.

However, CSS is not currently able to style a sibling element that is before a hovered element (it can't 'go back up' the DOM). But it can style a sibling element that follows the hovered element.

So the first change is to put the button element before the moon element. Now when the button element is hovered we can select its immediate sibling using the + combinator and from there we can select the rotate and moon elements to give them the animations required for rotating and spinning. (In this case we have left the definition of rotate as it is in the code in the question and introduced the spin animation to keep the star spinning around its center).

Now when the button is hovered the star rotates (moves in a large circle) and spins (rotates about its own center).

This snippet also makes the star spin when it is hovered and doesn't have any movement when there is no hovering. Obviously you can change the styling to have what you want there. Also the counterrotation is removed and the -webkit- prefixes, just to simplify things (and you don't want -webkit- with no vanilla setting set as well as some browsers may not interpret it).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      position: relative;
      right: -500px;
      bottom: -150px;
    }
    
    .moon,
    .star {
      background-position: center;
      /* Center the image */
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      /* Do not repeat the image */
      background-size: 120%;
      /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    
    .moon {
      background-color: transparent;
      background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bcIk.png");
      position: absolute;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      margin: 50px;
    }
    
    .star {
      position: relative;
      background-color: transparent;
      background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjbgR.png");
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    
    button:hover+.moon .star,
    .star:hover {
      animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes spin {
      from {
        transform: rotateZ(0deg);
      }
      to {
        transform: rotateZ(360deg);
      }
    }
    
    button:hover+.moon .rotate {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      animation: circle 10s infinite linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes circle {
      from {
        transform: rotateZ(0deg);
      }
      to {
        transform: rotateZ(360deg);
      }
    }
    
    button {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 16px 32px;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: 2px solid green;
      display: inline-block;
      transition-duration: 0.3s;
      position: relative;
      left: -350px;
      border-radius: 50px;
      bottom: -100px;
    }
    
    button:hover {
      background-color: green;
      color: white;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid white;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: green">
  <button>Hover</button>
  <div class="moon">
    <div class="rotate">
      <div class="star"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Couldn't hope for a better answer! Thanks! :)